# Concrete 5 - Cron to Clear Cache

Tags: concrete5

We have inherited a concrete 5 site and they're having a few issues with it, what seems to fix the issue is clearing the cache... Instead of doing this manually is it possible to set this up automatically via a cron job? Looking at the code I can see to call the clear cache function just calls `flush::cache();` is it as simple to just create a .php file that runs `flush::cache();`.

I've also found these plugins, has anyone used them before?

https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/clear-cache/

The version they're running is: Currently Running 5.5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CacheVac addon job. https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/cache-vac